# Can you lock down Cpanel/WHM access to certain IP's?

Tags: apache-2.2, security

Is it possible to only allow access to Cpanel/WHM to certain IP's? I know how to do it for standard folders, but I don't believe that will work for this purpose as they are on different ports or something & don't exist in the standard directory structure.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using [Host Access Control](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/DenyAccess) which is part of cPanel.

For example:

```
Daemon      Access List  Action  Comment
cpaneld     1.2.3.4      allow   Allow cPanel from my specific IP
cpaneld     ALL          deny    Deny access from all other IPs
```

Comment: Thanks. I have just been having a dig around WHM & found the `Configure Security Policies` section & something about "Limit logins to verified IP Addresses" - any idea if that's basically the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

In apache2 configuration

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from IP.AD.DR.ESS
    Deny from All
</Directory>
```

Then restart apache2

Comment: What does phpmyadmin have to do with cpanel/whm?

Comment: Oops my bad. a VirtualHost container has a directory statement. It is within this area you can ALLOW or DENY by IP address. But i see CPanel provides a means to do this without having to edit configuration files manually.